# Order of evaluation of classes?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, enums

In a file `lib.py` I defined a functional class `C` and an enumeration class `E` as follows:

```
class C:
    a = None
    def meth(self, v):
        if v == E.v1:
            print("In C.meth().v1")
            a = E.v1
        if v == E.v2:
            print("In C.meth().v2")
            a = E.v2


from enum import Enum
class E(Enum):
    print("In Enum")
    v1 = 1
    v2 = 2
```

Then, I import the two classes into my module `main.py` and use the enumeration:

```
from lib import C
from lib import E

c = C()
c.meth(E.v1)
```

When running, I get the following output:

> `In Enum`
>   `In C.meth().v1`

Now, since Python is an interpreted language (at least, when using IDLE), I'd expect to get an error on the reference to the enumerations in the method `meth`. Since there is no error, and it seems to run OK, I wonder what are the (ordering) rules for referencing classes in the same module, and in between different modules? Why is there no error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name lookup happens at run time. So when you are defining class `C` and its method `meth`, then the lookup on `E` isn’t done yet. So it’s not a problem that you define it *afterwards*. Instead, the lookup happens when you call the method.

Also, name lookup happens by going up the scope, so `meth` will find the original `E` declared on module level, regardless of whether you import it in your `main.py` or not. Since you also import `E` in `main.py`, which is a reference to the *same* object, you can reference the same enum value in there too.

See also this example:

```
>>> def test(): # foo is not defined at this time
        print(foo)
>>> test()
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
>>> foo = 'bar' # after defining foo, it works:
>>> test()
bar
```

When defining methods, variables are never “embedded”; the methods only contain the names and those names are looked up at run-time. However, due to how Python does the lookup, names of local variables are always “around” even if they haven’t been initialized yet. This can result in `UnboundLocalError`s:

```
>>> def test():
        print(foo)
        foo = 'baz'
>>> test()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

One might expect that `foo` would be looked up in the outer scope for the first print, but because there is a local `foo` (even if it wasn’t initialized yet), `foo` will always* resolve to the local `foo`.

(* The `nonlocal` statement allows to make `foo` non-local, resolving it to the outer scope—again for *all* uses of `foo` in that method.)

Comment: Thanks. Importing `E` on the `main.py` level is done for the reference in that module (when calling `c.meth`), of course.

Comment: Your code addition is interesting. So, what it means is that Python keeps a reference to an unknown object when parsing the definition, and only links it with the actual object when evaluating the expression? This means that I could change the definition of `foo` between evaluations of `test()`?

Comment: It doesn’t keep a reference to an unknown object, but rather just keeps the *name* (`foo` in this case). And then only when the function is executed, a *name lookup* happens to find out what object belongs to that name (if there even is one). And yes, you can change the value of `foo` between calls to get different results.

Comment: I actually meant the *definition* (as in its *type*) of `foo`, not the value.

Comment: ... actually, IIRC, once defined, an object cannot be re-defined, is that correct? (new to Python here)

Comment: Well, `foo` is just a name that points to an object (i.e. the value is the object). And you can change that all the time, including its type, yes. There is no real variable “declaration” in Python. The only thing that would occur in this context are `UnboundLocalError`s; I’ll add an example for that to the answer.

Comment: @ysap: A name does not have a type.  The object the name refers to has a type.  In some cases an object's type can be changed, but that has nothing to do with having `a = 1` and then later `a = list()`.

Comment: @EthanFurman - thanks. I guess this answers the question of re-definition of a name.

Answer (score 1):

When a module is imported, the commands are executed from top to bottom. Inside a `class`-definition, the commands are also executed, to define the methods inside the class. A `def` defines a method, but the commands inside the `def` are not executed, but only parsed.

Comment: OK, so how does the interpreter know what `E.v1` is in order to correctly parse the command?

Comment: It knows it at runtime. Only the commands immediately in the class definition are executed. There is nothing executed from the methods. Therefore in your example, if you would run "c.meth(E.v1)" another time, you would just get "In C.meth().v1" another time, without "In Enum". "In Enum" is printed at class "creation" time (in fact just before calling the metaclass for actually creating the class). I suggest you run this in a debugger (e.g. pydevd) to see what's really going on and when.

Comment: It's parsed as a name lookup, but it doesn't do the name lookup until the method is run.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to understand the order of evaluation in your code is is to watch it execute:

http://dbgr.cc/q

Press the play button on the far right of the debug buttons and it will automatically step through.

I think what is confusing to you is that when `class E` is defined, all statements inside of the `E` class are run. This is the case for every class definition. This includes calling the print function to say `"In Enum"`, as well as defining the `v1` and `v2` members of the `E` class.

The line `c.meth(E.v1)` isn't executed until both the `C` and the `E` classes have been defined, which means that `E.v1` has also already been defined. This is why there is no error like you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks. The order of execution is pretty evident from the output of the `print` statements that I inserted in the code (and in my actual code there is also an `__init__()` method defined, so its `print` is seen as well). What confused me is that I expected an interpreted language to require that a name is defined before using it. I thought there is no "late binding" so-to-speak. Evidently, my reasoning gap was the implementation of OO concepts in an interpreted language. I am just used to the C way of thinking.